# BeautifulSoup place content outside the real element while reading or parsing

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have to parse content of last dd and take its text as list of its child-p texts. See the screenshot below:
[image: The parse target]
I used the flllowing code:

```
with open('strange_dl.html') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    target=soup.dl.find_all('dd')[-1]
    p_elements=target.find_all('p')
```

Unexpectedly it returns the results, which is on the screenshot below:
[image: Bug number one]
So you can see that it return not all the actual p and also twised the second p element.

When I started to dig deeper I find that has corrupted html inside itself:
[image]

You can reproduce it with beautifulsoup4 from Anaconda and the html snippet below:

```html
 <dl data-test="memory-book-bank-details" class="definition-list padding-default">
            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Полное наименование</dt>
       <dd>АКБ «ЧУВАШКРЕДИТПРОМБАНК» ПАО</dd>
      
            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Город</dt>
       <dd data-test="memory-book-bank-city">Чебоксары</dd>
      
            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Номер лицензии</dt>
       <dd data-test="memory-book-bank-license">
        1280
                &nbsp;|&nbsp;
         <a href="http://www.cbr.ru/credit/coinfo.asp?id=970000003"
            target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Информация на сайте ЦБ</a>
              </dd>
      
            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Причина</dt>
       <dd>отзыв лицензии</dd>
      
            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Дата</dt>
       <dd>07.11.2019</dd>
      
            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Причина отзыва лицензии</dt>
       <dd class="margin-bottom-zero"><p>Банк России принял решение в соответствии с п.&nbsp;п. 6 и 6.1 части первой ст.&nbsp;20 Федерального закона &laquo;О банках и банковской деятельности&raquo;2, руководствуясь тем, что Чувашкредитпромбанк:

 <p>&mdash; допускал нарушения законодательства и нормативных актов Банка России в области противодействия легализации (отмыванию) доходов, полученных преступным путем, и финансированию терроризма. Кредитная организация представляла в уполномоченный орган неполную и некорректную информацию, в том числе по операциям, подлежащим обязательному контролю;
 </br>&mdash; проводил сомнительные операции, связанные с продажей наличной иностранной валюты;
 </br>&mdash; допускал нарушения порядка расчета капитала и занижал величину необходимых к формированию резервов на возможные потери. По оценке Банка России, отражение в финансовой отчетности достоверной величины капитала и реальных кредитных рисков, принимаемых кредитной организацией, приводит к значительному (более 35%) снижению размера собственных средств банка. В результате возникают основания для осуществления мер по предупреждению несостоятельности (банкротства) и создается реальная угроза интересам кредиторов и вкладчиков;
 </br>&mdash; нарушал федеральные законы, регулирующие банковскую деятельность, а также нормативные акты Банка России, в связи с чем регулятор в течение последних 12 месяцев неоднократно применял к нему меры, в том числе вводил ограничения на привлечение денежных средств физических лиц.

 <p>На балансе Чувашкредитпромбанка образовался значительный объем корпоративных кредитов низкого качества. Банк России направил в адрес кредитной организации предписание с требованиями об адекватной оценке принимаемых рисков и отражении в отчетности своего реального финансового положения.</dd>
          </dl>
```

Comment: What is your question / problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need to get all the text which displaying on first screenshot, however Beautifull Soup gives me only two paragraphs from three and duplicates the second one(see screenshot two)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `<p>` tags are not closed with a closing paragraph tag `</p>`.
BeautifulSoup gets confused for where the paragraphs end and it supposes it to be where the next one starts. But the last one cannot be guessed due to no following paragraph. This is why you are having all these problems.
Easiest solution is to put paragraph closing tags in your html.

```
<dl data-test="memory-book-bank-details" class="definition-list padding-default">
                                            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Полное наименование</dt>
                        <dd>АКБ «ЧУВАШКРЕДИТПРОМБАНК» ПАО</dd>

                                            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Город</dt>
                        <dd data-test="memory-book-bank-city">Чебоксары</dd>

                                            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Номер лицензии</dt>
                        <dd data-test="memory-book-bank-license">
                            1280
                                                            &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                <a href="http://www.cbr.ru/credit/coinfo.asp?id=970000003"
                                   target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Информация на сайте ЦБ</a>
                                                    </dd>

                                            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Причина</dt>
                        <dd>отзыв лицензии</dd>

                                            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Дата</dt>
                        <dd>07.11.2019</dd>

                                            <dt class="font-bold color-text">Причина отзыва лицензии</dt>
                        <dd class="margin-bottom-zero"><p>Банк России принял решение в соответствии с п.&nbsp;п. 6 и 6.1 части первой ст.&nbsp;20 Федерального закона &laquo;О банках и банковской деятельности&raquo;2, руководствуясь тем, что Чувашкредитпромбанк:</p>

<p>&mdash; допускал нарушения законодательства и нормативных актов Банка России в области противодействия легализации (отмыванию) доходов, полученных преступным путем, и финансированию терроризма. Кредитная организация представляла в уполномоченный орган неполную и некорректную информацию, в том числе по операциям, подлежащим обязательному контролю;
</br>&mdash; проводил сомнительные операции, связанные с продажей наличной иностранной валюты;
</br>&mdash; допускал нарушения порядка расчета капитала и занижал величину необходимых к формированию резервов на возможные потери. По оценке Банка России, отражение в финансовой отчетности достоверной величины капитала и реальных кредитных рисков, принимаемых кредитной организацией, приводит к значительному (более 35%) снижению размера собственных средств банка. В результате возникают основания для осуществления мер по предупреждению несостоятельности (банкротства) и создается реальная угроза интересам кредиторов и вкладчиков;
</br>&mdash; нарушал федеральные законы, регулирующие банковскую деятельность, а также нормативные акты Банка России, в связи с чем регулятор в течение последних 12 месяцев неоднократно применял к нему меры, в том числе вводил ограничения на привлечение денежных средств физических лиц.</p>

<p>На балансе Чувашкредитпромбанка образовался значительный объем корпоративных кредитов низкого качества. Банк России направил в адрес кредитной организации предписание с требованиями об адекватной оценке принимаемых рисков и отражении в отчетности своего реального финансового положения.</p></dd>
                                    </dl>
```

Comment: Thanks. You find it. The only problem is that this is not my html but html from one site. Despite html is not correct browser render it correctly. Finally I parsed it using low level parsing with python HTMLParser. I will post my code soon